# Formatting JSON data in Python with djano

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, parsing

I'm having trouble formatting JSON data and displaying certain fields in Python.

What I'm looking to do is only display the name and the price on a webpage via Django.

I've tried many different ways, but the only code that works right now is showing all the data, not just the name and price. The data is as follows:

```
{
  "totalCount_str": "10134",
  "items": [
    {
      "adjustedPrice": 306988.09,
      "averagePrice": 306292.67,
      "type": {
        "id_str": "32772",
        "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/inventory/types/32772/",
        "id": 32772,
        "name": "Medium Ancillary Shield Booster"
      }
    },
    { "..." }
  ],
  "pageCount": 1,
  "pageCount_str": "1",
  "totalCount": 10134
}
```

**item.py:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Collects the item price chart
page = requests.get('api.eveonline.com/xxxxx')

# Creates a BS4 object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

item_name = soup.find(name_='')
item_price = soup.find(averagePrice='')

print(name)
print(price)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to use an HTML parser to read JSON. BeautifulSoup has no reason to be here. Use the appropriate tool: the built in JSON library; requests will even call it for you.

```
data = page.json()
item = data["items"][0]
print(data["averagePrice"])
print[data["type"]["name"])
```

Comment: Thanks I was told I could use bs4 to scrape json..that information was wrong. Thanks for showing me the way(correct)!